# Nginx configuration for Deluge

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx running on a CentOS server where i installed Deluge and configured a server block for him.
In my browser, mydomain.com redirects to Deluge webUI but **www**.mydomain.com redirects to a web page of the hoster.
In my dns, i have an entry for "www" and "mydomain" to the server ip.

Here's the Deluge server block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts.conf :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.localhost:8112;
                proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base   "/";
        }
}
```

Have you any idea ? :)

Comment: can you provide a `curl` output for `www.mydomain.com` this will tell us if you are getting a redirect somewhere. Also as this could be a DNS problem the real domain name would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Check DNS to make sure propagation is working by using [this site](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) or `dig`.

   ```
   dig mydomain.com
   dig www.mydomain.com
   ```

   Verify that both of those point to the same IP address
2. Your nginx configuration looks a little off.  I would have used this:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

       location / {
           # proxy_pass http://www.localhost:8112;
           proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base   "/";
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8112;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answers !
Problem solved by passing to https. (I auto-generated a ssl cert)

Drifter 104 > curl sent me html code of hoster page.

2ps > I modified the vhost conf as following :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dl.domain.com www.dl.domain.com;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8112;
                proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base   "/";
        }
}
```

I also added ssl_sertificate entry in vhost conf and redirected all http flux to https.